# By what prayer Arjuna prayed Lord Shiva while obtaining Pashupatastra?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, shiva, history, prayer

Lord Shiva provides Pashupatastra to Arjuna as described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03040.htm) of the Mahabharata. While giving Pasupatastra Lord Shiva states:

> न त्वेतत् सहसा पार्थ मोक्तव्य पुरुषे कचित् ।
>   जगद विनाशयत् सर्वमल्पतेजसी पातितम् ।।
>   अवध्यो नाम नास्तयत्र त्रैलक्ये स चराचरे ।
>   मनसा चक्षुषा वाचा धनुषा च निपातयत् ।।
>   
>   O son of Pritha, this weapon should not be hurled without adequate cause; for if hurled at any foe of little might it may destroy the whole universe. In the three worlds with all their mobile and immobile creatures, there is none who is incapable of being slain by this weapon. And it may be hurled by the mind, by the eye, by words, and by the bow.

Arjuna must have Prayed Lord Shiva with some prayers before obtaining such a powerful Astra. So, **By what prayer Arjuna prayed while receiving Pashupatastra?**

Comment: You can hear the same prayer [here](https://youtu.be/5jV49dvTdCk?t=6393) in Telugu (it lasts for 2 mins.) by poet [Nannaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nannayya) who translated part of MB to Telugu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When Arjuna recognized that the Kirata is none other than Mahadeva. Then he prayed Mahadeva with this Prayer as described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03039.htm) of Mahabharata:

> कपर्दिन् सर्वदेवेश भगनेत्रनिपातन ।
>   देवदेव महादेव नीलग्रीव जटाधर ।।
>  
>   O Kapardin, O chief of all gods, O destroyer of the eyes of Bhaga, O god of gods, O Mahadeva, O you of blue throat, O you of matted locks,
>   
>   कारणानां च परमं जाने त्वां त्र्यम्बकं विभुम् ।
>   देवानां च गतिं देव त्वत्प्रसूतमिदं जगत् ।।
>  
>   I know you as the Cause of all causes. O you of three eyes, O lord of all! You are the refuge of all the gods! This universe has sprung from you. 
>   
>   अजेयस्त्वं त्रिभिर्लोकै सदेवासुरमानुषै ।
>   शिवाय विष्णुरुपाय विष्णवे शिवरुपिणे ।।
>  
>   You are incapable of being vanquished by the three worlds of the celestials, the Asuras, and men. You are Shiva in the form of Vishnu, and Vishnu in the form of Shiva.
>   
>   दक्षयज्ञविनाशाय हरिरुद्राय वै नमः ।
>   ललाटाक्षाय शर्वाय मीढुषे शूलपाणये ।।
>  
>   You destroyed the great sacrifice of Daksha.  I bow to your HariRudra form. You hast an eye on your forehead. O Sarva, O you that rainest objects of desire, O bearer of the trident, 
>   
>   पिनाकगोप्त्रे सूर्याय मंगलाय च वेधसे ।
>   प्रसादये त्वां भगवान् सर्वभूतमहेश्वर ।।
>  
>   O wielder of the Pinaka, O Surya, O you of pure body, O Creator of all, I bow to you. O lord of all created things, I worship thee to obtain thy grace.
>   
>   गणेशं जगतः शम्भु लोककारणकारणम् ।
>   प्रधानपुरुषातीतं परं सुक्ष्मतरं हरं ।।
>  
>   You are the lord of the Ganas, the source of universal blessing, the Cause of the causes of the universe. You art beyond the Pradhana and Purusha, you are the highest, you are the subtlest, O Hara
>   
>   व्यतिक्रमं मे भगवन् क्षन्तुमर्हसि शंकर ।
>   भगवन् दर्शनाकांक्षी प्राप्तोऽस्मीमं महागिरिम् ।।
>  
>   O illustrious Shankara, it behoveth thee to pardon my fault. It was even to obtain a sight of thyself.
>   
>   दयितं तव देवेश तापसालयमुत्तमम् ।
>   प्रसादये त्वां भगवन् सर्वलोकनमस्कृतम् ।।
>  
>   I came to this great mountain, which is dear to thee and which is the excellent abode of ascetics. Thou art worshipped of all worlds. 
>   
>   न मे स्यादपराधोऽयं महादेवेतिसाहसात् ।
>   कृतो मयामज्ञानाद् विभर्दो यस्त्वया सह ।
>   शरणं प्रतिपन्नाय तत् क्षमस्वाद्य शंकर ।।
>  
>    Let not this rashness of mine be regarded as a fault--this combat in which I was engaged with thee from ignorance. O Sankara, I seek thy protection. Pardon 
>   me all I have done."

As Arjuna asked forgiveness from Lord Shiva as he unknowingly fought with him, Mahadeva smilingly forgives him

> वैशम्पायन उवाच
>   
>   तमुवाच महातेजा: प्रहस्य वृषभध्वज ।
>   प्रगृह रुचिरं वाहुं क्षान्तमित्येव फाल्गुनम् ।।
>  
>   Vaisampayana continued, "Endued with great might, the god whose sign was the bull, taking into his the handsome hands of Arjuna, smilingly replied unto him, saying, 'I have pardoned thee. And the illustrious 
>   Hara, cheerfully clasping Arjuna with his arms, once more consoling Arjuna said as follows.

Comment: In the last shloka, who is referred to as "Falguna" ? Arjuna or Krishna ?

Comment: @user96551 Arjuna is being referred as Falguna...